# Yamaha Crux-S Shock Absorbers-Rear

Tags: yamaha, shock-absorber

I have Yamaha 'CRUX-S' model and back shock absorbers are hard. I was asked to get them changed with better by a mechanic as they are hard. What type will make me a better ride. Can I use 'CRUX' Shock absorbers or any other better suggestion is appreciable? Thank You

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you leave the part about better ride in the question, it will get closed as opinion based. Also, this question is precariously close to being a shopping question. If you limit it to what will physically fit (what will work in place of your current), I think we can salvage the question and make it viable.

Answer (score 1):

The rear shocks being two hard can be solved in a number of ways, depending on what is available:

**1) Adjust the preload.**
A number of modern motorcycle shocks and forks have adjustment for preload. In fact if your motorcycle shocks or forks have any sort of adjustment available, it's probably for preload. Preload is the amount of squeezing force applied to the spring beyond the normal weight of the motorcycle and rider. It's usually achieved with a set of locknuts on threads that will tighten down onto the spring, or a stepped collar that spins into a few different positions. Squeezing the spring will have the affect of making the spring more firm, as it will take more energy to continue to squeeze it compared to when it was fully extended.

**2) Swap out the spring.** Springs in forks and shocks are designed for a specific weight range, usually measured in kg/mm. Preload adjustments will help fine tune them, but the adjustment will only go so far before all the preload has been removed and no more can be taken out, or the spring is compressed to the point that it no longer offers sufficient travel. If you want a softer or stiffer shock beyond what the adjustment will give, you need a spring that was manufactured with a higher or lower rating.

I would start by checking if you have a preload adjustment on the shocks, and if so, taking some out. This will have the affect of making the shocks feel softer, and also raising the ride height in the rear a little bit. Make sure both are adjusted to the same setting evenly, or you will negatively affect handling and stability.

If that isn't an option, or does not go as far as you need it to, you need to look at new springs. At this point I'd recommend talking to a suspension specialist, as changing springs isn't the kind of thing that people do themselves. You need special tools to compress the shock. An expert will also be able to help you determine the rating of the springs you already have, and a rating that would suit your weight.